# Cleaning a Data Frame

Tags: android

I have a data frame with 2500 rows and 14 columns. One of the columns is named `Interest.Rate` in which every entry is followed by a `%` sign. Can you please tell me how to remove the `%` sign from all the entries of the `Interest.Rate` column.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an android programmer, but if your data frame is a text file, e.g. called `data-frame.txt` and separated by one spaces each:

```
Sth Interest.Rate Sth
1 2% 3
4 5% 6
```

you can use `awk` for this:

```
awk "/Interest/{print} !/Interest/{gsub(/%/,\"\");print}" data-frame.txt
```

or, if you have a different field separator than space (e.g., _), you can tell awk about this by:

```
awk -F"_" "/Interest/{print} !/Interest/{gsub(/%/,\"\");print}" data-frame.txt
```

tested system: windows xp sp3, cmd.exe, msys-1.0 awk